# error with user for pip install with custom index-url

Tags: python, docker, pip, nexus

I have an internal nexus server where I store my python packages.

When I try to run

`pip install --index-url=https://my_pip_user:my_pip_pass@my_pip_url ...`

while building docker image I'm getting

`my_pip_user is not a valid value for user option, please specify a boolean value like yes/no, true/false or 1/0 instead.`

The error is not thrown if cmd is run just in bash.

I've tried to put `index-url` into `~/.pip/pip.conf` but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar problem before, just check your environment variables, make sure you do not have any env vars which start with "**PIP_**", e.g. "**PIP_USER**", otherwise it will consider this is a pip command option and will be passed to pip command.

Reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Had a somewhat similar error message:

```
2 is not a valid value for verbose option, please specify a numerical value like 1/0 instead.
```

Was caused by a discrepancy in pip versions while working with different virtual environments. It appears to be the case, that *pip 20.0.2* does not support `verbose = 2` in pip.conf, whilst *pip 23.3.1* does support this level.